# Cut off extension of filename

Tags: javascript, regex, filenames

I have a list of filenames like

```
index.min.html
index.dev.html
index.min.js
index.dev.js
There.are.also.files.with.multiple.dots.and.other.extension
```

I want to cut off the extensions of the filenames, but the problem is that I can only use `match` for this task.

I tried many regular expressions looking like `"index.min.html".match( /^((?!:(\.[^\.]+$)).+)/gi );` to select the filename without the last dot and extension, but they selected either the hole filename, nothing or the part before the first dot. Is there a way to select only the filename without extension?

Comment: Can you explain on why you have to use `match`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why regex?  Simple substring expressions make this a lot simpler:

```
var filename = 'index.something.js.html';

alert(filename.substr(0, filename.lastIndexOf(".")));
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd go for

```
/(.+)\..+$/mi
```

[demo @ regex101](http://regex101.com/r/vW9fC5)

See the demo, especially the matches. It only gives you the filename without the last `.` and the characters afterwards.

Comment: This works, but when I use `foo.bar.something.else".match(/(.+)\..+$/mi);`, it should return the filename without extension

Comment: @Cubinator73 this isn't possible with regexes. the `match`-method will always return the... well... match. For your scenario you'll always have to **match** the full name and **capture** the interesting part. Thus the filename without extension is simply contained in a capturing group that you can access on the match. When you run the match you posted in a browserconsole you will see that `match[1]` is the part that you want to get (`foo.bar.something`). `match[0]` is always the whole match and every `index > 0` are the capturing groups.

Answer (score 3):

How about this one: `(.*)\.[^\.]+`
See http://regex101.com/r/xI6qM0

Comment: This works too, but, as I said to Basti M, when I use `foo.bar.something.else".match(/(.*)\.[^\.]+/gi);`, it should return the filename without extension

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution would be to just slice off the last element:

```
var a = "index.min.html";
var b = a.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.');
```

Or, even better, using JavaScript's String function `substr`:

```
var b = a.substr(0, a.lastIndexOf("."));
```

Why do you *have* to use `match`?

Comment: This works also great. Paddy's is shorter, but thank you too. :)

Answer (score 0):

Could do the trick, too:

```
function baseName(str) {
    if (typeof str !== 'string') return;
    var frags = str.split('.')
    return frags.splice(0,frags.length-1).join('.');    
}
```

Repl:http://repl.it/OvI

jsPerf: http://jsperf.com/string-extension-splits

**Result:**

`substr` is the fastest of all options in this thread. Kudos to the other guys.